# Delphi 10.4 не понимает class TClientSocket

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Давно не программировал. Решил вспомнить, чтоб не отупеть. Установил Delphi 10.4, до этого была установлена Delphi XE Architect (в ней, раньше, на Win7 всё работало). Но при миграции она перестала открываться без ошибок и я решил обновить версию. Установил 10,4 и она тоже не работает со старыми проектами - клиент-серверными приложениями, выдаёт ошибку "class TClientSocket not found", разве эту систему в разработке клиент-серверного ПО упразднили? Сейчас иные технологии?
Вижу два пути решения:

1. Не знаю как (сервера отключили) установить Delphi XE
2. Каким-то образом заменить в проектах class TClientSocket, на более современный, если он устарел.

Подскажите, что можно и лучше сделать, чтобы вернуться к разработке\доработке старых проектов?

Comment: Откажись от TClientSocket, и используй Indy. Не просто так TClientSocket вырезали из языка. Он хоть и простой и понятный но глючный до безбожества!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они есть, только не установлены по умолчанию  - видимо, подразумевается пользование установленной библиотеки Indy

`Components - Install packages`

ищем `ПапкаСтудии\bin\dclsocketsXXX.bpl` (у меня в D12 XXX=290, номер версии)

После установки смотрим на вкладке «Internet».